# Can't get data in the template from a model associated with one-to-many relationship

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, foreign-keys

I'm new to programming and I'm stuck in this problem.  Thanks in advance.

I have the following models in a one to many relationship:

1) Paciente Model:

```
class Paciente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cpf_paciente = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
```

2) Processo Model:

```
class Processo(models.Model):
    cid = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    paciente = models.ForeignKey(Paciente, 
                on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='processos')
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paciente = models.ForeignKey(Paciente, 
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='processos')
```

The view that performs a QuerySet:

```
    @login_required
    def renovacao_rapida(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            busca = request.GET.get('b')
            usuario = request.user.pk
            pacientes = Paciente.objects.filter(
                (Q(nome__icontains=busca) | 
                Q(cpf_paciente__icontains=busca)) 
                & Q(usuario_id__in=Usuario.objects.filter(id=usuario))
            )

        contexto = {'pacientes': pacientes}



        return render(request, 'processos/renovacao_rapida.html', contexto)
    else:
        pass
```

And the template rendered by the View:

```
<ul>
{% for paciente in pacientes %}
    <li> {{ paciente.processos }}       
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**My goal is to show in the template the Processo assigned to Pacientes.**

Although there are processos assigned to pacientes in the DB, I get in the Template the following output:

- processos.Processo.None
- processos.Processo.None ......

Whereas when I try {{ pacientes.usuario }}, the output is as expected:

- User1
- User2 ...

Comment: You need to iterate over `paciente.processos.all`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked.